# Sample Bluemix-Watson Node.js visualization webapp doesn't show my devices

Tags: node.js, web-applications, ibm-cloud, intel-edison, watson-iot

I am currently using Bluemix for my project based on IOT. I'm pushing data from Intel Edison onto Bluemix. To make it easier to visualize the device data by the end user, I have hosted a NODE.JS sample app available at https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/visualizingdata_sample.html.

The app is intended to display a list of all the available devices in the organisation, but it doesn't seem to show a list of my devices.

I'm currently using three organisation ids in a account and couldn't specify the organisation id of my interest while uploading the Node.JS app.

The command that had to be used is : cf target-o  -s dev
but it gives the following errors:
C:\Users\KUNAL\Desktop\project\devicedatadisplay>cf target-o 43tjaz -s dev
'target-o' is not a registered command. See 'cf help'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jijLA.jpg)

Can anyone please suggest what can I do to make it work.

Thanks and regards
Kunal Arora

Comment: Put a space between `target` and `-o`

Comment: Besides putting a space between `target` and  `-o` you have to specify your organization name as well.

Comment: @Kunal_Arora did changing the command to add space and org name resolve your problem?

Comment: I've tried all sorts of combinations but it doesn't seem to work. Please see below:                           C:\Users\KUNAL\Desktop\project\devicedatadisplay>cf target -o 43tjaz kunalarora
-s dev
Organization '43tjaz' not found.
FAILED

C:\Users\KUNAL\Desktop\project\devicedatadisplay>cf target -o kunalarora 43tjaz
-s dev
Space 'dev' not found.
FAILED

C:\Users\KUNAL\Desktop\project\devicedatadisplay>cf target -o kunalarora -s dev
Space 'dev' not found.
FAILED

Comment: What is your organisation name?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give your Bluemix Organization name and not your IoT organization ID.

```
cf target-o <your_bluemix_org> -s dev
```

Replace `<your_bluemix_org>` with your Bluemix organization ID and ensure space dev exists within that bluemix organization

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an old version of the visualiztion application, can you please  try the updated version?
https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/rickshaw4iot/releases/tag/v0.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inputs everyone. The following steps helped resolve the issue:

1) Downloading the latest app version from -
https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/rickshaw4iot/releases

2) Using a space between target-o as target -o

3) Using the Bluemix Organisation name in this command. This is different from the IOT service organisation name (IOT service has 6 characters long organisation name).

4) 'dev' keyword is to be replaced by the name of your space in Bluemix.

The details regarding organisation name and space can be found by looking at the top right corner of the Bluemix dashboard.

The top right corner typically corresponds to -

organisation name : space

Kind regards,
Kunal Arora